# How can I convert type-erasure wrappers or use them as another wrapper

Tags: c++, c++17, type-erasure

I created sets of functions using the type-erasure design pattern:

- `Encodable`: `encode()`, `decode()`
- `Printable`: `print()`

If I overload these functions with `MyStruct1` and `MyStruct2`, I'll be able to wrap these types in the type-erasure wrappers `Encodable` and `Printable` and indirectly call those functions using the wrappers functions and store `MyStruct1` and `MyStruct2` in a heterogeneous container like `std::vector<Encodable>`.

My problem arised when I wanted to use these objects both as an `Encodable` and a `Printable` or when I wanted to convert one to the other.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Encodable {
private:
  struct EncodableConcept {
    virtual ~EncodableConcept() = default;
    
    virtual std::vector<uint8_t> _encode() const = 0;
    virtual bool _decode(std::vector<uint8_t> const& byteVector) = 0;
    
    virtual std::unique_ptr<EncodableConcept> clone() const = 0;
  };
  
  template<typename EncodableT>
  struct EncodableModel : public EncodableConcept {
    EncodableModel(EncodableT inst) : _inst{std::move(inst)}
    {}
    
    std::vector<uint8_t> _encode() const override {
      return encode(_inst);
    }
    bool _decode(std::vector<uint8_t> const& byteVector) override {
      return decode(_inst, byteVector);
    }
    
    std::unique_ptr<EncodableConcept> clone() const override {
      return std::make_unique<EncodableModel>(*this);
    }
    
    EncodableT _inst;
  };
  
  friend std::vector<uint8_t> encode(Encodable const& inst) {
    return inst.pimpl->_encode();
  }
  friend bool decode(Encodable & inst, std::vector<uint8_t> const& byteVector) {
    return inst.pimpl->_decode(byteVector);
  }
  
public:
  template<typename EncodableT>
  Encodable(EncodableT inst)
  : pimpl{std::make_unique<EncodableModel<EncodableT>>(std::move(inst))}
  {}
  
  Encodable(Encodable const& other)
  : pimpl(other.pimpl->clone())
  {}
  
  Encodable& operator=(Encodable const& other) {
    // Copy-and-swap idiom
    Encodable tmp(other);
    std::swap(pimpl, tmp.pimpl);
    return *this;
  }
  
  // Move is not implemented to prevent the pimpl to be nullptr after move operation.
  // Upon move the copy constructor or the copy assignment operator is going to be called.
  
private:
  std::unique_ptr<EncodableConcept> pimpl;
};

class Printable {
private:
  struct PrintableConcept {
    virtual ~PrintableConcept() = default;
    
    virtual void _print() const = 0;
    
    virtual std::unique_ptr<PrintableConcept> clone() const = 0;
  };
  
  template<typename PrintableT>
  struct PrintableModel : public PrintableConcept {
    PrintableModel(PrintableT inst) : _inst{std::move(inst)}
    {}
    
    void _print() const override {
      print(_inst);
    }
    
    std::unique_ptr<PrintableConcept> clone() const override {
      return std::make_unique<PrintableModel>(*this);
    }
    
    PrintableT _inst;
  };
  
  friend void print(Printable const& inst) {
    inst.pimpl->_print();
  }
  
public:
  template<typename PrintableT>
  Printable(PrintableT inst)
  : pimpl{std::make_unique<PrintableModel<PrintableT>>(std::move(inst))}
  {}
  
  Printable(Printable const& other)
  : pimpl(other.pimpl->clone())
  {}
  
  Printable& operator=(Printable const& other) {
    // Copy-and-swap idiom
    Printable tmp(other);
    std::swap(pimpl, tmp.pimpl);
    return *this;
  }
  
  // Move is not implemented to prevent the pimpl to be nullptr after move operation.
  // Upon move the copy constructor or the copy assignment operator is going to be called.
  
private:
  std::unique_ptr<PrintableConcept> pimpl;
};

struct MyStruct1 {
  MyStruct1(int x) : x{x} {}
  int x;
};
std::vector<uint8_t> encode(MyStruct1 const& inst) {
  std::vector<uint8_t> byteVector;
  // ...
  return byteVector;
}
bool decode(MyStruct1 & inst, std::vector<uint8_t> const& byteVector) {
  // ...
  return true; // Success
}
void print(MyStruct1 const& inst) {
  printf("MyStruct1{%d}\n", inst.x);
}


struct MyStruct2 {
  MyStruct2(float y) : y{y} {}
  float y;
};
std::vector<uint8_t> encode(MyStruct2 const& inst) {
  std::vector<uint8_t> byteVector;
  // ...
  return byteVector;
}
bool decode(MyStruct2 & inst, std::vector<uint8_t> const& byteVector) {
  // ...
  return true; // Success
}
void print(MyStruct2 const& inst) {
  printf("MyStruct2{%f}\n", inst.y);
}

std::vector<Encodable> readFromSomewhere() {
  std::vector<Encodable> readEncodables;

  // Read from file, socket, etc...
  readEncodables = {MyStruct1{1}, MyStruct2{2.2}, MyStruct1{3}, MyStruct2{4.4}};

  return readEncodables;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<Encodable> readEncodables = readFromSomewhere();

  // TODO: How can I print readEncodables using the overloaded print functions?
  // For example:
  for (Encodable const& obj : readEncodables) {
    // print(obj); // Compilation error (thanks god)
  }

  // TODO: How can I convert an Encodable to a Printable object?
  std::vector<Printable> convertedPrintables;
  for (Encodable const& obj : readEncodables) {
    // convertedPrintables.emplace_back(obj); // Compilation error (thanks god)
    // print(*convertedPrintables.crbegin());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

1. **How can I easily convert an `Encodable` to a `Printable` and vice versa?**
2. **Can I somehow directly use an `Encodable` as a `Printable` if the `print()` function is overloaded for the given type?**

My only (bad) solution is to create a templated `get()` function in the wrappers to unwrap the contained object run-time. If the type of the template argument matches the object the unwrap succeeds and I can rewrap it into a `Printable` or just directly use the overloaded `print()` free function.

```
template<typename EncodableT>
EncodableT* get() const {
  EncodableModel<EncodableT>* modelPtr = dynamic_cast<EncodableModel<EncodableT>*> pimpl.get());
  if (modelPtr == nullptr) return nullptr;
  return &modelPtr->_inst;
}
```

However the usage of this function would be rather ugly and inconvenient:

```
for (Encodable const& obj : readEncodables) {
  auto* ptr1 = obj.get<MyStruct1>();
  if (ptr1 != nullptr) {
    print(*ptr1);
    continue;
  }
  auto* ptr2 = obj.get<MyStruct2>();
  if (ptr2 != nullptr) {
    print(*ptr2);
    continue;
  }
  // ...
}
```

This could be made a bit nicer by storing `std::type_index` the wrappers, but I'd still have create if-else or switch statements for each type for calling a simple `print()` free function...

Comment: You'd have to create a new type like `EncodableAndPrintable`. With type-erasure you only keep the functionality needed to qualify for such a concept and nothing else. Such conversion wouldn't make sense because not all `Encodable`s can be `Printable`s and vice versa.

Comment: It could make sense if we could check compile or run-time if the underlying type is eligible to be an `Encodable` or a `Printable`. But let's say I create the class type `EncodableAndPrintable`. I'd still need to convert the return value of `readFromSomewhere()` to `print()` the decoded objects.

Comment: How about `std::unique_ptr<Printable> Encodable::cloneAsPrintable() const = 0;`?

Comment: Nothing is going to derive from `Encodable`. Making it pure virtual would make the class abstract, thus unusable. Even if it's not virtual, making it a member function is a bad idea, because that would introduce an undesired dependency. As a free function with an `Encodable` as an argument is OK. However, how would you define that function? That was my first question.

Comment: You could add a pure virtual `EncodableConcept::MakePrintable` method, and have `EncodableModel` implement it (would need a bit of template metaprogramming to return null or some other empty state in case the underlying class doesn't actually have `print` method). `Encodable` could then provide a method or a conversion operator implemented in terms of this virtual function. Note that both `Encodable` and `Printable` store the underlying object by value, so what ends up in `Printable` thus produced would have to be a copy of the original object.